# How to align text right to a line

Tags: tables, math-mode, equations, programming

I want to write a Haskell function definition like this:

[image: Function definition]

But i don't know how to insert that lines.

How can i write something like this in LaTex?

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE.  We usually like to see what you've tried so far; it gives us an idea of what parts we'll need to explain.  Have you looked into the listings package?  (And I assume you want to typeset something to get that output, as opposed to define a TeX function that would do the same thing as this Haskell function.)

Comment: In the [CTAN category "pseudocode"](https://ctan.org/topic/pseudocode) there are a lot of packages which offer functionality to typeset such definition.  Just pick one, try to reproduce your picture and then come back with a *specific* question when you have problems.

Comment: I just want to know how to align formulas right to a vertical line.

Comment: Please update the title of the question to be specific about the vertical and horizontal line that you're trying to reproduce

Comment: I would advise not to vote to close this question yet: give the OP the time to react to the solicitations that have been made.  I suggest waiting at least 12 hours since the original post.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Lines drawn with a regular `array`:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{eqparbox,amsmath}

\begin{document}

\[
  \begin{array}{| r @{} l }
    P ~ : ~ & [\text{Num}] \mapsto \text{Bool} \\
    \rule[-10pt]{0pt}{0pt}Q ~ : ~ & \text{Num} \mapsto [\text{Num}] \mapsto \text{Bool} \\
    \cline{1-1}
    \multicolumn{2}{|l}{\rule{0pt}{12pt}\eqmakebox[lhs][r]{$P.xs$} ~ \doteq ~ Q.0.xs} \\
    \multicolumn{2}{|l}{\eqmakebox[lhs][r]{$Q.n.[]$} ~ \doteq ~ \text{True}} \\
    \multicolumn{2}{|l}{\eqmakebox[lhs][r]{$Q.n.(x \triangleright xs)$} ~ \doteq ~ n \geq 0 \wedge Q.(n + x)xs}
  \end{array}
\]

\end{document}
```

Struts: See [Column and row padding in tables](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/31704/5764)